# HBase Java API HTrace error

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I want to create a Java API to access HBase DB, but I am always facing with this error in my project;

```
15/12/14 20:34:22 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.34.184:2181,192.168.34.173:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0xa80e050x0, quorum=192.168.34.184:2181,192.168.34.173:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
15/12/14 20:34:22 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.34.184:2181
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:222)
    at api.ClientOperations.creatTable(ClientOperations.java:69)
    at api.ClientOperations.main(ClientOperations.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/Trace
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.Trace
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

But I added HTrace jar in my project

[image: Referenced libraries]

HBase version: 1.1.2

Hadoop version: 2.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add right jar file to your project, add htrace-core-3.1.0 jar file to project class path then run it.
[htrace-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.htrace</groupId>
   <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```